# Accessing items in GridView

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq, gridview

I have a GridView and I am updating it through LINQ through C#. I want to access the elements in my GridView and store them in the variable. Then I will pass these variables into my LINQ query.

How should I access the items in my GridView? Here is my code:

```
protected void gvShowComm_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string productID = gvShowComm.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["Product_ID"].ToString(); //Working!
    string planName = gvShowComm.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["PlanName"].ToString(); //Working!
    string hiComm = gvShowComm.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["HiCommissionOld"].ToString(); //Working!
    string lowComm = gvShowComm.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["LowCommissionOld"].ToString(); //Working!

    gvShowComm.DataBind();
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" Height="233px" Width="602px" ID ="gvShowComm" 
    CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowEditing = "gvShowComm_RowEditing" 
    OnRowUpdating = "gvShowComm_RowUpdating" 
    OnRowCancelingEdit = "gvShowComm_RowCancelingEdit" DataKeyNames = "Product_ID, PlanName, HiCommissionOld, LowCommissionOld">       
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowCancelButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: please mention if the grid is bound via autogeneratecolumns, bound field or tremplate field. and also whether you have set DataKeyNames in the gridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GridViewUpdateEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.aspx) has properties on it that allow you to get at the [Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.keys.aspx), [OldValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.oldvalues.aspx), and [NewValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues.aspx) collections for a particular row.

You *could* access it like so:

```
protected void gvShowComm_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    //Product_ID is a column that I am displaying in my GV!
    int Product_ID = Int32.Parse(e.Keys["Product_ID"]);

    Entity_Product_Point ev = new Entity_Product_Point();

    ev.MyDateTime = DateTime.Parse(e.NewValues["MyProp"]);

    // And so on...
}
```

But this sucks pretty hard! ASP.Net can do the work for you, using one of the DataSource classes available. For your purposes you should look into the [LinqDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb547113.aspx)

It is worth noting that while the DataSource classes can be useful and nice, they have quite a bit of magic going on, and you can pretty much throw out the possibility of using any testable patterns with them. (see [WebFormsMVP](http://webformsmvp.com/))

If that isn't a concern, then go for it. But achieving clean separation of concerns is better in the long run. In that case you would need to implement a facade wrapper around your business logic and use the [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a4kyhcx.aspx).

Either way you are better off than manually rooting around in key/value pair collections looking for values and then converting them back to their proper types.

Comment: I have 2 different DB where I m updating my values in. In LDS you can update to only 1-1 basis. Thats is why I want to hard code it.

Answer (score 2):

Something like Produce_ID sounds like a key field and if it is, you can do

```
var keyValue =  gvShowComm.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
if(keyValue!=null)
int Product_ID = Convert.ToInt32(keyValue);
```

or else

there is `e.NewValues[]` and `e.OldValues[]` that you could use.

Comment: I tried this. I am getting this err:Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: +1. @Nice_Name: define Product_ID as DataKeyNames in the gridviews markup